# Passing an arraylist of object from servlet to jsp failed

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

this things is giving me headache for the past 3 days already. I tried to store the resultset that i get from the database and store inside an arraylist of object then pass it to the jsp for display, but after running the program, it gave me this error:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c2hI6.png)

anyone have any idea how to solve this problem? Thanks in advance!
below is my code:
menu.java

```
@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse     response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

        //Create connection object
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(request.getServletContext().getInitParameter("url"), request.getServletContext().getInitParameter("username"), request.getServletContext().getInitParameter("password"));
        String sql = "select name,price,imageurl from food";
        stmt = conn.createStatement();
        rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
        class food {

            String name;
            double price;
            String imageurl;

        }
        ArrayList<food> foodDetail = new ArrayList<food>();

        while (rs.next()) {
            food temp = new food();

            temp.name = rs.getString("name");
            temp.price = rs.getDouble("price");
            temp.imageurl = rs.getString("imageurl");

            foodDetail.add(temp);

        }
        request.setAttribute("menu", foodDetail);
        RequestDispatcher req = request.getRequestDispatcher("menu.jsp");
        req.forward(request, response);

    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Menu.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Menu.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } finally {

        try {
            rs.close();
            stmt.close();
            conn.close();
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
        }

    }
```

menu.jsp

```
<%
        class food {

            String name;
            double price;
            String imageurl;
        }


        ArrayList<food> foodDetail = (ArrayList<food>) request.getAttribute("menu");
        food temp = new food();
java.util.Iterator it = foodDetail.iterator();
        while (it.hasNext()) {

            food z = (food) it.next();

            out.println(z.getName());


        }


    %>
```

Comment: Any error in console ?

Comment: your food class in different what you pass and what you trying to case in

Comment: you need to import food class what you use in servlet in jsp as <%@ page import="your.package.food" %> instead defining another class in jsp

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove this class `food` from jsp page:

```
  class food {

        String name;
        double price;
        String imageurl;
    }
```

And instead try to import class food like this `<%@ page import="package.food " %>` in your page jsp.
And add a backslash to path:

```
   RequestDispatcher req = request.getRequestDispatcher("/menu.jsp");
```

Answer (score 0):

Your food class in servlet used in list `ArrayList<food> foodDetail = new ArrayList<food>();` which is you trying to pass is trying to cast in `org.apache.jsp_menu$1food` which is defining in jsp itself. remove the declaration in jsp of class food and use `<%@ page import="your.package.food" %>` it should be same as what you used in servlet as I have commented.